# Неудаляемое приложение

Tags: java, android

Как переопределить метод `onDisable`, чтобы нельзя было удалить приложение с правами администратора?

[image: DeviceAdminReceiver]

Comment: Если правильно понимаю вопрос: onEnabled вызывается в момент, когда приложение становится администратором, а onDisabled - когда оно перестаёт им быть. Думаю, можно в теле onDisabled вызывать super.onEnabled(context, intent).

Comment: Нет, не получилось. Android всё равно выполняет действие отключения.
```
@Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(true){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Admin Enabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "reverse Enabled");
            super.onEnabled(context, intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Admin Disabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "onDisabled");
            super.onDisabled(context, intent);
        }
    } 
```

Comment: Можно каким-нибудь способом заблокировать кнопку "Отключить админ профиль", если сравнивать с приложениями safe kids, find my kids у них данная кнопка деактивирована.